# WPF MVVM customizing ListView cell to insert hyperlink and change text color

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a GridView cell in a ListView that is defined as a TextBlock and bound to a string on my ViewModel. I want to be able to change parts of the text into hyperlinks and part into different colors programatically.

Here is the XAML for the GridView cell:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#dfdfdf" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" Margin="3"/>    
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

And here's what it looks like at the moment:

[image: WPF Listview cell]

An example of the text that is bound would be:

```
<color:#ff0000>Test item</color>
Test item 2
<link:http://www.google.com>Test hyperlink</link>
```

I have no problem with the regex to parse the bound text and pull out the required information but how would I go about changing the TextBlock into different colors and add a hyperlink?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can put multiple **[Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run.aspx)** elements inside a TextBlock and style then however you like.

Here is an example with a working hyperlink which even supports MVVM :)

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#dfdfdf" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock  Margin="3">
            <Run Text="{Binding Data}" />
            <Run Text="Some more data" Background="Red" />
            <Run Text="Click Me" Foreground="Blue" TextDecorations="Underline" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                      <local:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LinkClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
                   </i:EventTrigger>   
                 </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Run>
        </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Note:
The `Interaction.Triggers` are from `System.Windows.Interactivity` and the `EventToCommand` from MVVMLight.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Blachshma's answer, but using a hyperlink right in there with the `Run` objects:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding Data}" />
  <Run Text="Some more data" Background="Red" />
  <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
  </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Clearly I have a `Command` and `Text` properties to bind to for the hyperlink. Will look exactly the same, but will also respond to the command's `CanExecute` predicate (hyperlinks go grey).